# How to pipe webpack-dev-server output to a node script

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, fish

I am trying to pipe the output of [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server) `--progress` to another node script. The command I'm using is:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress | ./index.js
```

And the contents of `index.js` are:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  var input = process.stdin.read();
  if (input !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(`stdout: ${input}\n`);
    var command = input.trim();

    console.log(input.length);  //this one is always 1 longer
    console.log(command.length);

    if (command === 'quit') {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }
});
```

I see an output, but this isn't getting piped to `index.js`, it's being sent straight to the terminal and being printed out.

If I run the following, it works:

```
tail -f file | ./index.js
```

How should I go about changing either the webpack-dev-server logging or `index.js` so that I can process the logging in my script? I am using a [fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell, using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) and nodejs version v12.18.3.

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you see isnt stdout but stderr?

use 2>| to redirect stderr to stdin
and &| to redirect stdout and stderr